# Is there a way to test for a scrollbar with just CSS?

Tags: css, firefox

I want to know if the element is showing vertical scrollbars or not, and if it is possible to do this with CSS only.

This only needs to work for Firefox by the way.

Comment: CSS is not generally used for logical-processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean using selectors to test, no, there isn't such a selector in standard CSS (because the presence of scrollbars is calculated during rendering), nor can I find any selectors in [this list of Mozilla vendor extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) that do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS cannot accomplish as this requires to be able to monitor the element, not apply styles.

Using jQuery

```
   var element = $("#yourdiv");
   if(element.get(0).scrollHeight > element.height()) {
       console.log('scroll bar is visible');
   }
```